# Fullscreen webpage presentation

Tags: html, silverlight, flash

I am developing a web system for training and the trainer can show the content by zooming with the css3 property that increases the size of the screen.

What I'm trying to achieve is a PowerPoint style presentation, which fills the screen. The problem is that my webpage can be a combination of HTML, Flash, image or audio, or even 4 at a time.

How can I accomplish this? One idea I have is to create an image of the contents of the webpage and attach it to a flash and put it in full screen. Is there a better solution or maybe some software or something?

Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT**

I know browser have the functionality to go full screen, but what I'm trying to do is take a part of the webpage (because in the page are the menu, toolbars, etc) that is in a div.

Comment: Use a Kiosk mode of the browser by pressing F11?

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 Fullscreen API:
http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

```
// mozilla proposal
element.requestFullScreen();
document.cancelFullScreen(); 

// Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome Canary)
element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); 

// Firefox (works in nightly)
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 

// W3C Proposal
element.requestFullscreen();
document.exitFullscreen();
```

Also, check out this for making a presentation with HTML5:
http://slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's best to let the user control this. F11 works in all browsers (that I know of) to toggle full-screen on and off.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support pushing F11 to go into full screen mode....

Comment: I was going to say this but thought it be too obvious

Answer (score 0):

Most web browsers have a full screen mode - hit F11 on a Windows machine with either Internet Explorer or Firefox and they will go full screen. Hit escape to exit full screen.

You may also want to conside using S5 ( http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/ ) to make HTML based presentations.

Good luck!

Comment: Your clarification has made it less clear for me. Please consider carefully wehat it is you want to do then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp

This use  element.requestFullscreen() method